# Java: Waiting for mouse input (click)

Tags: java, swing, input, mouse, jframe

I am making some sort of turn-based battle system in a JFrame where the player clicks a button when it's his turn. The problem is: how can the program wait for a mouse click on the button? It goes like this:

while it is the player's turn {

- wait for mouse input
- if input == attack (for example)

  ```
     -> attack
  ```

  else if input == item

  ```
     -> use item
  ```

  and so on

Comment: i have put it in a while loop but the contents of the frame are not displaying i think it is because of the while loop

Comment: what? my question is how can the program wait for a mouse click on the button?

Comment: No while loop -- that's just not how GUIs work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't wait for a click; you let Swing do that for you. Instead, you put whatever you want to do into an `ActionListener` and attach it to the button, so it gets executed when the button is clicked.

As far as the turns go, you just need a member variable someplace that keeps track of whose turn it is; the button handler then has to look at that variable to know what to do.

One good way to structure things, by the way, might be to have a `Player` class, and a `Game` class, and a member in `Game` called `currentPlayer`. Then the `ActionListener` (which keeps the `Game` object as a member variable of its own) could look at `currentPlayer` in the `Game` and simply invoke `makeMove()` on the appropriate `Player` object.

Comment: Ok I'll think of another solution. Thanks!